# Trap not activated when calling functions

Tags: ksh, bash-trap

I am using set -e and a trap handler to produce error messages is my ksh scripts.

```
#!/bin/ksh
set -e

myexit()
{
    if [[ $1 != 0 ]]; then
         echo "ERROR: Script $0 failed unexpectedly with signal $1!"    
    fi
}

settrap()
{
    for sig in INT TERM EXIT; do
        #echo "setting trap for $sig..."
        trap "code=$?;trap - INT TERM EXIT;myexit $code \"$sig\"; [[ $sig == EXIT ]] || kill -$sig $$" $sig
    done
} 
settrap
```

Now I have the strange behavior that this works for calling old-style functions, but not for functions calling functions.

```
test1()
{
    echo "test1"
    eval test2
}

test2()
{
    echo "test2"
    return -1
}

test3()
{
    settrap
    echo "test1"
    eval test2
}
```

What will happen?

- test1 will exit but not call myexit
- test2 and test3 will call myexit.

**Question**: Why does test1 not cause myexit to be called when the call to test2 returns -1?

---

Edit: The problem is not because functions have local traps. As explained [here](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/korn/ch08_04.htm): Old-style POSIX functions (those created using the name() syntax) share traps with the parent script.

Comment: Traps are local to function, that's probably why. Please see : https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/korn/ch08_04.htm section 8.4.1. Hope it helps

Comment: You have a quoting problem in the settrap function: you appear to be expecting `$sig` to be expanded within single quotes.

Comment: @AndreGelinas Old-style functions do not share that behavior with the new syntax.

Comment: @Beginner but doesn't that mean that `$sig` will be expanded to its current value at expansion-time, which will always be `EXIT` after the loop has completed? The string can't capture the current value at trap-setting-time.

Comment: @amon fixed the quotes

Comment: @glennjackman you were right all along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior seems to be a bug with signal bubbling in ksh88.

[ksh function (not posix) trap not receiving signals -HUP, -TERM but does receive -INT](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1454804)

I switched to using dtksh which is a newer version on my system and everything works fine.

This shebang solves the issue:

```
 #!/usr/dt/bin/dtksh
```